# How to customize the homepage title without creating new pages?

Tags: 8

I can set up my page like this and it works fine:

```
somepage:
  path: '/my_page'
  defaults:
    _title: 'My custom page title'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\MyController::content'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

BUT I need the `path` to be empty, so I tried this: `path: '/'` - not working. What I need is to be able to customize default homepage title of drupal 8 (without having to create new pages).

Tried `path: '/'` `path: /` `path: ''`. No success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the homepage for D8 is set to `/node` (similar to D7).
And unlike Drupal 7, this is a view. So, adding a title is as simple as adding the title to the view. (Views in core, yay!)

1. Go to `/admin/structure/views/view/frontpage`.
2. Add title to the view
3. Save

It is as simple as that!
If you save any other page as your homepage, then you could set the title to the route as you have already specified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module to set home page title

> The Metatag module allows you to automatically provide structured
>   metadata, aka "meta tags", about a website. In the context of search
>   engine optimization, when people refer to meta tags they are usually
>   referring to the meta description tag and the meta keywords tag that
>   may help improve the rankings and display of a site in search engine
>   results.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a title to the view works fine for customizing the page title.

But there is one more problem as the Navigation Menu entry "Home" is not editable.
So I went again in the view settings and created a "Normal menu entry" with my custom tile. Then I edited the Navigation Menu settings and to disable the original "Home" menu entry and now I have the custom "Home" menu entry.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and it worked for me. I went to the url alias and saw that the front page was node 1. If it is not I sugeste to go there and discover what node is. Then  change the title property.

admin/config/search/path

I hope that help for some of us.

Best regards